# Changing font size in Pandoc generated PDF document

Tags: pdf, yaml, pandoc

I'm trying to change the font size in a Pandoc generated PDF document using a yaml. The settings are made in `layout.yaml` template below;

```
---
title: "Core Concepts in Mechanics"
geometry: margin=3cm
fontsize: 20pts
output: pdf_document
...
```

I then call Pandoc as below

```
Pandoc --latex-engine=pdflatex -s -o CoreConceptsInMechanics.pdf CoreConceptsInMechanics.md layout.yaml
```

The font size does not change at all. The rest of the settings work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The [yaml metadata block](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-yaml_metadata_block) is supposed to go at the top of your markdown file.

The standard LaTeX document classes support only 3 different font sizes, `10pt`, `11pt` and `12pt` (note that it's not `12pts`). If you need larger fontsizes you have to specify a different class, e.g.

```
---
fontsize: 20pt
documentclass: extreport
...

# My title

my doc
```

Finally, if you want it to be in two different files, the order is important AFAIK, it should be:

```
pandoc -o output.pdf layout.yaml CoreConceptsInMechanics.md
```